# Prove that: $\sqrt{x^2+21}+\sqrt{2y^2+14}+\sqrt{z^2+91}\ge 19$

Tags: inequality

Let $x, y, z$ be real number such that $xy+yz+zx=11$. Prove the inequality:

$$\sqrt{x^2+21}+\sqrt{2y^2+14}+\sqrt{z^2+91}\ge 19$$

I think that inequality can be solved by Minkowski. Equality holds if only is $(x;y;z)=(2;1;3)$...But I couldn't continue...

Comment: All your questions seam to be on inequalities.

Comment: Source of this question, please?

Comment: metacompactness: Yep... I am learning about it ... :D
GerryMyerson: From my friend... He composed it :D

Comment: Minkowski fails. For instance, for $x=1$, $y=2$ and $z=3$ we have $\sqrt{x^2+2y^2+z^2+21+14+91}=12<19$.

Comment: Thanks .... But can you help me?

Comment: Then why don't you ask your friend how to solve it?

Comment: oh,It's nice inequality, I have solve it by $AM-GM$

Comment: @GerryMyerson: One challenge from my friend :D

Comment: @math110: How? You can show your solution? :D [AM-GM in root?] :-ss

Comment: A challenge from your friend --- so you put it on the internet? Sorry, I'm not buying.

Comment: Now,I post my solution

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I know .. Thanks for your reminder ... And thanks for holding as off-topic from you  :D

Comment: @math110: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

we can prove this inequality $x,y,z$ are positive numbers.

By cauchy-Schwarz inequality have
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}}{n}}\ge\dfrac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}{n}$$
where $a_{i}>0,i=1,2\cdots,n$\
then
$$\sqrt{x^2+21}=5\sqrt{\dfrac{\dfrac{x^2+1}{5}+1+1+1+1}{5}}\ge 5\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{5}}}{5}=\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{5}}+4$$
$$\sqrt{2y^2+14}\ge \sqrt{2}\cdot 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{2\dfrac{y^2+1}{2}+6}{8}}\ge 4\cdot\dfrac{2\sqrt{\dfrac{y^2+1}{2}}+6}{8}$$
$$\sqrt{z^2+91}=10\sqrt{\dfrac{\dfrac{z^2+1}{10}+9}{10}}\ge 10\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{z^2+1}{10}}+9}{10}$$
then 
$$LHS\ge \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{5}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y^2+1}{2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{z^2+1}{10}}+(4+3+9)\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{100}}+16$$

since
$$(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)=(x^2+1)[(y+z)^2+(yz-1)^2]\ge [x(y+z)+(yz-1)]^2=(xy+yz+xz-1)^2\ge 100$$

by this way: we only prove this $x,y,z$ are positive numbers, becase
$$x\longrightarrow |x|,y\longrightarrow |y|,z\longrightarrow |z|$$
then we have 
$$|xy|+|yz|+|zx|\ge xy+yz+xz\ge 11$$

and I very like this inequality, who creat?  Thank you

Comment: Intelligent solution :) . Thanks ! This inequality is creat by my friend :D .

Comment: A nice solution.